# What is the derivative of $\frac{x}{2-\tan x}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am too stupid to figure this out so I won't even try anymore

$$y = \frac{x}{2 - \tan x}$$

I am sure this will take someone about four seconds to solve, but I spent about ten minutes looking at it and I have no clue how to continue, this is probably wrong but I ended up with this.

$$ \frac{2\tan x - 2x + x\tan x}{4 - \tan x + \tan^2 x}$$

No clue how to continue from there and it might be wrong, I can't keep the signs straight and I am not sure if I distributed it correctly, I could be wrong on that part.

Comment: Have you ever heard about chain rule for the differentiation?

Comment: I know about it but I did not think to use it.

Comment: Generally better to have a more descriptive title. Certainly not an impossibly difficult, and, for many, not even a difficult problem, so this title doesn't give much help to the reader.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews and for the future, when people with the same problem would use search and this one won't show up.

Answer (score 4):

Using the quotient rule:

$$y' = \dfrac{\frac{d}{dx}(x)\cdot (2 - \tan x) - x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(2 - \tan x) }{(2 - \tan x)^2}$$

**Now** $$\bf\frac d{dx}(2 - \tan x) = \frac d{dx}(2) - \frac d{dx}(\tan x) = 0 - (\sec^2 x) = -\sec^2 x,\;$$ (this one place where you "mis-stepped", I believe).

And clearly $\quad\frac{d}{dx}(x) = 1$.

The other "mis-step" is in your computation of $\;(2 - \tan x)^2.\quad $ So the denominator will be $\;(2 - \tan x)^2 = 4 - 4\tan x + \tan^2 x$:

$$y' = \dfrac{1\cdot(2 - \tan x) - ( x(-\sec^2 x))}{4 - 4\tan x + \tan^2x} = \frac{2 - \tan x + x\sec^2 x}{4 - 4\tan x + \tan x^2}$$

Comment: Isn't your quotient rule wrong? I thought it was the derivative of the top first.

Comment: Where $\sec^2 x$ did go? :)

Comment: $y'$ is fine, as stated above. If you'd like, you can express $\tan x = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, and $\sec^2 x = \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 x}$, but more work is then required to simplify.

Comment: Is this clear now, Jordan?

Comment: @amWhy: This looks like a lot of messy algebra too! ;-) +1

Answer (score 4):

$$
y' = \left ( \frac x{2-\tan x} \right )' = \frac {x' (2- \tan x) - x (2-\tan x)'}{(2-\tan x)^2} = \frac {2 - \tan x - x \left (-\tan x \right )'}{(2-\tan x)^2} = \\
= \frac {2 -\tan x + \frac x{\cos^2 x}}{(2-\tan x)^2} = \frac {2 \cos^2 x - \sin x \cos x + x}{\cos^2 x (2-\tan x)^2} = \frac {2 \cos^2 x - \sin x \cos x + x}{(2\cos x-\sin x)^2}
$$
Probably you can simplify it little bit more, using double angles, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ combinations, and such, but in general it should be sufficient.